# Occasional EFI fuse blowing while starting to move (eg: traffic signal)

Tags: fuse

My car is currently in workshop..!!!

It was going off sometimes when you start moving from a traffic signal, and we found out the EFI fuse was blown and it happened again after I replaced the fuse, but not right away after it was replaced. The car is at a workshop for past two days and they are saying that the problem would be a wire that has lost it's insulation somewhere which occasionally touches the body of the car when the car is running and that would result in a fuse failure, and they couldn't yet find the wire in past two days. If someone can help me resolve this issue. It would be a great help. At least a way to find the wire or if the fuse is blowing due to some other reasons?

By the way, my car is Toyota echo 2002 model.

Comment: Looking for a chaffed wire takes time, patience and perseverance. Only needs a pinhole to cause the fuse to blow, can take a **long** time and that means money...

Comment: One possibility is to cut the existing wire at both ends and run a replacement, then see if it still happens...

Comment: It happened in the middle of the road almost one month ago for the first time and I got it to the same workshop and they found out it is a fuse after a whole day of inspection. And now after a period of almost 20 days and  It went off in the middle of a traffic signal while I was coming back from a 1 hour drive and I replaced the fuse again from the spot and the fuse got blown very next day early morning while I was heading to work and was just 1 km away from home, then I took the car to the workshop by the evening.  *This is what happened. * I couldn't smell anything perticular there.

Comment: You need to narrow down the possibilities by looking at a wiring diagram.  There will be very few wires that are part of the EFI that could cause enough current To blow a fuse when shorted.  Once you have identified the possibilities, you need to trace their path to the engine.